# How to return key for column with smallest values

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
d= {'1': {         '2': 1,  '3': 0,  '4': 0, '5': 1,  '6': 29 }
   ,'2': {'1': 13,          '3': 1,  '4': 0, '5': 21, '6': 0  }
   ,'3': {'1': 0,  '2': 0,           '4': 1, '5': 0,  '6': 1  }
   ,'4': {'1': 1,  '2': 17, '3': 1,          '5': 2,  '6': 0  }
   ,'5': {'1': 39, '2': 1,  '3': 0,  '4': 0,          '6': 14 }
   ,'6': {'1': 0,  '2': 0,  '3': 43, '4': 1, '5': 0           }
   }
```

I want to write a function that returns the column where all the values are <2 (less than 2).

So far i have turned the dictionary into a list, and then tried a lot of things that didn't work... I know that the answer is column number 4.

This was my latest attemp:

```
    def findFirstRead(overlaps):
        e= [[d[str(i)].get(str(j), '-') for j in range(1, 7)] for i in range(1, 7)]
        nested_list = e
        for i in map(itemgetter(x),nested_list):
            if i<2:
                return x+1
            else:
                continue
```

...and it was very wrong

Comment: `d['4']` is `{'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0}`, which has values `2` and `17` in there. `d[3]` is the only one with all values in the nested dict < 2. Am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: That is the row, the column has the values 0,0,1,-,0,1. I have posted the matrix version for the dictionary so it is easier to see.

Answer (score 5):

The following set and list comprehension lists columns where the column has a max value of 2:

```
columns = {c for r, row in d.iteritems() for c in row}

[c for c in columns if max(v.get(c, -1) for v in d.itervalues()) < 2]
```

This returns `['4']`.

Comment: That's not what OP is asking. You give the "row" with all values less than two. OP wants the "column" with all values less than two.

Comment: @Tinctorius: I am not so certain; I think this is *exactly* what the OP is asking. This `returns the column where all the values are <2`.

Comment: Tinctorius is right. I got 3, which is the row, but it want the column. (

Comment: @vdbuilder: no, the indices are given by strings, and they start at 1. `'3'` does not correspond with the "fourth column".

Comment: @Tinctorius: Right, it wasn't clear that the dicts were supposed to be matrix rows.